# Асинхронное программирование

Tags: javascript

Привет программистам! Подскажите, где почитать про асинхронное программирование?
[Асинхронное программирование](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/async) - здесь
описано очень недостаточно-понятным языком. В каких книгах вы встречали эту тему?

Comment: Вообще там написана несусветная чушь, что для javascript.ru неудивительно. Предлагаю задать конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Нужно в гугль вводить `asynchronous programming javascript` если по запросу `асинхронное программирование` нет путней инфы!

Comment: я имменно искал по запросу асинхронное программирование

Comment: это именно одно и оже только на английском...

Comment: А именно по Deffered самая крутая книга - документация и примеры в www =)

Comment: Заинтересовался, решил проверить так ли плохо в сети с этой темой. Через несколько минут...


[Отличная статья](http://www.smira.ru/2009/02/10/deferred-async-programming/) и непосредственно по запросу "асинхронное программирование" в гугле.

Кстати, весь *Блог Андрея Смирнова* (статья оттуда) очень хорош.

Странно, столько горячего обсуждения, а на правильный материал никто внимания не обратил.

Answer (score 1):

Я изучаю вот по этим книгам, также сохранил последовательность прочтения:

1. http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-1034-X.html
2. http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1327-2.html
3. http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1366-1.html

**Кратко от себя:** *Первая книга Читается очень трудно, но только начиная с третьей главы пойдет красота :). Дальше, вторая книга, там куча всяких примеров, можно брать и использовать, честно сказать чаще обращаюсь в гугл а не в книгу. Ну и наконец третья книга, считайте, что получили подробное описание API по этим библиотекам. На мой взгляд такую связку трудно реализовывать двумя библиотеками, интерфейс одной библёй, запросы другой, лучше сразу перейти к изучения jQuery.*

Comment: да З.Ы. я купил книжки на распродаже по 100 р, за каждую, тупо повезло :)

Comment: все начинаю читать!СПС

Comment: Вынужден минуснуть по той же причине. @zloctb, идите лучше от простого - событий DOM и будет вам счастье. Потом и к событиям XHR будет легко перейти.

Comment: @karmadro4, что вы пишите... СОБЫТИЙ DOM!!! Мне Яндекс выдал http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%AB%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%AF+DOM&lr=213, вы сейчас научите.

DOM (от англ. Document Object Model — «объектная модель документа») — это не зависящий от платформы и языка программный интерфейс, позволяющий программам и скриптам получить доступ к содержимому HTML, XHTML и XML-документов.

За такой ответ вынужден буду сообщить администрации сайта!

Comment: @archi_sova - лично я не вижу абсолютно никакого повода обращаться к администрации, более того, мне абсолютно непонятна ваша реакция

Comment: @archi_sova Странно как-то получается, что википедией вы пользоваться умеете, а яндексом нет.

Comment: @archi_sova, на самом деле, сообщать администрации в данном конкретном случае - это уже перебор, но отчасти Ваше возмущение понятно. я Вам советую всё-таки концентрироваться на том, что Вы помогли человеку найти ответ и это *уже* неплохо))

Comment: @archi_sova, [копипаста клёвая](http://encyclopediadramatica.se/Cool_story_bro), а остальной бессвязный лепет я не понял. Кстати, не вас ли недавно банили за бурную реакцию на комментарии? :-) В любом случае, то что вы оба вскочили на Гаррета и поскакали в неизвестном направлении - глупость.